# Passar Form + Variável por AJAX

Tags: ajax

Pessoal estou tentando passar meu FORM + a variavel OFFSET, porém não estou conseguindo.. Alguém pode me da um exemplo?

```
$("#btn-pass").click(function() {

    offset = offset + 5;
    pagina++;

    var data = $("#form-fatura").serialize();

    data.push({
        off: offset
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'code-source/return/ret_info_fatura.php',
        data: data,
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#btn-pass").prop('disabled', true);
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.codigo == "1") {

                $("#btn-pass").prop('disabled', false);
                $("#btn-back").prop('disabled', false);
                $("#container-fatura").html(response.fatura_animal);
                $("#pagina").html("Página: " + pagina);
            } else {
                $("#btn-pass").prop('disabled', true);
                offset = offset - 5;
                pagina--;
                $("#btn-back").prop('disabled', false);

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você der um console.log(data), você verá como os dados são organizados com um padrão assim `[nameTag]=[value]`, caso tenha um input `<input type="text" name="nome" value="Vinícius">` no console do seu navegador será impresso `nome=vin%C3%ADcius`.

Caso hajam 2 ou mais inputs, os dados serão separados pelo caractere `&`, ou seja, caso houvesse dois inputs:

```
<form id="formulario">
<input type="text" name="inputa">
<input type="text" name="inputb">

<input type="button" id="button" value="enviar">
</form>
```

O console exibirá `inputa=valueDoInput&inputb=valueDoInputb`.

No seu caso basta adicionar a data `"&off="+offset`
ou

```
data += "&off=" + offset;
```

Comment: Genial! Funcionou.

Answer (score 2):

Uma possibilidade é utilizar o método `SerializeArray`

```
var data = $("#form-fatura").serializeArray();
data.push({name: "off", value: offset});
```

Comment: Já tentei também :\